# Dynamic Lookup Range in Evaluate Index without Loop

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create vba to evaluate an index forumla in a range, is there a way to run the match lookup value for each row without running a variable through a loop?  Sample code below:

```
'Column C Fill
'=IFERROR(INDEX('EMEA lists'!$F$2:$F$908,MATCH(B7,'EMEA lists'!$C$2:$C$908,0)),"no data found")
Range("C6:C" & wks2LastRow) = Evaluate("INDEX(" & wks3.Range("F2:F" & wks3LastRow) & ",MATCH(" & "<insert row reference>" & "," & wks3.Range("C2:C" & wks3LastRow) & ",0)))")
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code assumes that Column B (starting at B6) of the active sheet contains the lookup values.  It will first enter the formula in Column C (starting at C6) of the active sheet, and then converts the formulas into values...

```
With Range("C6:C" & wks2LastRow)
    .Formula = "=INDEX(" & wks3.Range("F2:F" & wks3LastRow).Address(External:=True) & ",MATCH(" & Range("B6").Address(False, False) & "," & wks3.Range("C2:C" & wks3LastRow).Address(External:=True) & ",0))"
    .Value = .Value
End With
```